# Shrinking drive space, need help?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Shrinking drive space, need help!
Ok I don't know how to word this nor have any searches produced results I need, i checked for the hyperfil.sys (no go btw) as i cleared that out, and i think this is a virus (unplugged my network cable), and what leads me to think virus is that my drive space (free) is literally shrinking in front of my eyes as im watching it...and I know i have a masive drive so i should have a few hundred gigs still left free...so what do you all think is going on here? virus or something else? i don't want to try and download any thing or install anything till i sort this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice program called [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/). Download and run it, it will tell you where all the space has gone.

Comment: Run it elevated to Administrator to get good info about the sizes of all folders, otherwise any folder it can't read is lumped into the "Unknown" category.  Even better, use Sysinternals `psexec` utility (from http://sysinternals.com/) to run it as user SYSTEM, then you see pretty much everything on your disk, and the "Unknown" category should be empty.